# How to get the n top elements of an rdd per value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I created an RDD of key/values this way:

```
RDD[(String, Int)]: rdd.map(row => row.split(1) -> 1).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

How can I get the top five elements based on values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rdd.top`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@takeOrdered(num:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):Array[T]) in order to avoid a full sort of the rdd:

```
rdd.top(5)(Ordering[Int].on(_._2))
```

This defines an order on the values and makes a single `O(n)` pass on the rdd to get the 5 top items per value.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did it :)